# libp2p node gives Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: tcp, libp2p

I have a libp2p running inside a nodejs server.

From outside the docker I can connect to the node by using p2p addr: `/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/3333/p2p/Q…` so I know the libp2p node is up and listening and docker-proxy is connecting to the container on that port.

The port is open as

```
sudo ufw status
```

says:

```
To         Action From

3333      ALLOW  Anywhere 
3333 (v6) ALLOW  Anywhere (v6)
```

also:

```
 sudo netstat -plunt | grep 3333
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3333           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6539/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::3333                :::*                    LISTEN      6545/docker-proxy
```

But from any other computer I get connection refused by both a libp2p node and the ubuntu command:

```
nc -zvw10 ip-address 3333
```

What is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: To show that a question has been satisfactorily answered, you should accept the answer that helped you the most; even your own answer can be accepted (after a waiting period)

Comment: It was my own answer.
Why the SOLVED was removed? I don't understand.

Comment: Because that's not how we know questions have been answered on Stack Overflow. We know that when you *accept* an answer, by choosing the check mark to the left of your answer.

Comment: I've been using this website for years and I din't know that. Imho there should also be a button to close the question which could say: choose and answer or just close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the libp2p node the ip address must be 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.0 or the real server's ip.

Then, when trying to remotely reach the libp2p node, the ip has to be that of the server (the one that `ping your-domain.com` returns)

Imo 80% of development pain comes from too simple examples in the "documentation"